# What am I doing wrong? Integration convergent . $\int_{1}^{B} \frac{e^x}{e^{2x}-1} dx$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

$$\lim_{B\to\infty} \int_{1}^{B} \frac{e^x}{e^{2x}-1} dx$$

This equals

$$=\lim_{B\to\infty} \frac{1}{2}\big(\ln |e^{x} - 1| - \ln |e^{x} + 1| \big) \bigg|_{1}^{B}$$

$$= \lim_{b\to\infty} \frac{1}{2}\bigg(\ln \bigg|\frac{e^x -1}{e^x + 1}\bigg| \bigg) \bigg|_{1}^{B}$$

$$= \frac{1}{2}\bigg(\ln 1 - \ln\bigg|\frac{e -1}{e + 1}\bigg| \bigg)$$

$$= -\frac{1}{2}\ln\bigg|\frac{e -1}{e + 1}\bigg|$$

Answer is undefined.

Comment: Why is the answer undefined?

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+B+-%3E+%5Cinfty+%5Cint_%7B1%7D%5E%7BB%7D+%5Cfrac%7Be%5Ex%7D%7Be%5E(2x)-1%7D

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_1%5Einfty+%5Cfrac%7Be%5Ex%7D%7Be%5E(2x)-1%7D+dx

Comment: Wolfram confuses me... Thanks

Comment: Notice that you and wolfram got the same result, he just wrote it with other functions - but if you calculate the number you got and it got, you'll get the same